# How to build different builds with different property in gradle through a script?

Tags: batch-file, call

I have bat script like this:

gradlew.bat mobile:clean mobile:build -Pmyargs=11

gradlew.bat mobile:clean mobile:build -Pmyargs=222

The second string do not work. How to fix it? Maybe I need other approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `call gradlew.bat ...` to temporarily run another script and then return. If you call a `bat` file from another `bat` file directly, you completely delegate to the called `bat` file and do not get back to the calling `bat` file.